# Can't insert keyframe on 2D

Tags: keyframes

[image]

im new on blender and recently ive been trying to add keyframe since i follow a video of creating a 2D animation with sprite sheet, but i can't insert any keyframe at all. ive been trying all the solution ive found on the internet but none works, ive been redoing the tutorial that ive followed on but the result are still the same

Comment: Are you sure this is the way they do it in the video you are following? You cannot insert a keyframe because there is no channel (like rotation, translation, scale or any other property that can be keyframed) in the _Dope Sheet_ yet. To get something there you must choose a property of the object to add a keyframe. For example, in the _3D Viewport_ press "I" and choose something like _Location_ from the context menu. But at this moment you are in _Edit Mode_, this will only work in _Object Mode_.

Comment: you mean like this? [https://imgur.com/a/8SZQqD0] i have try that too

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't animate UV map coordinates, at least not like you are trying to do. What blender version is your tutorial on ? Have you double checked you're doing exactly the same thing ?

Comment: the tutorial that i followed used blender ver 2.91.2, me too before ive updated mine to 3.0 because i thought maybe its a version error. also recently ive try the same way on my friend pc and it worked. i dont know perhaps the problem exist on my computer

Comment: @AshuraFirdaus So you're saying when in _Object Mode_, you cannot add a _Location & Rotation_ keyframe for example? In the image you linked in the comment, when you click on the already highlighted option you don't get a keyframe?

Comment: @gordon yeah, but when i try it on my friend pc , that worked

Comment: @AshuraFirdaus Is it just this file or generally every time you try to keyframe something, even in a new file and after re-opening Blender?

Comment: @Gordon , it never happened until today actually, not only this one almost all files that i try , i can't insert keyframe on it.

Comment: anyway thanks for all of the reply , i apreciate it, i think im just gonna finish this on my friend pc.

Comment: can you add a pointer to the tutorial, or is it paid?  This isn't the usual way to animate a sprite sheet, but it might be possible to make it work.